# Trying to retrieve JSONP from HTTP server from a HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, https, getjson

I have a website based on HTTPS, and I have a JS code the get data from a website based on HTTP. I get an error that the HTTP server is not trusted.
While the same code works on HTTP to HTTP. But not on HTTP to HTTPS.
This is the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.33k.com/player/playerudan.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://33k.thepuremix.net/json.xsl'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

For getting this data I use something like the following code:

```
var URL = "http://33k.thepuremix.net/json.xsl"
$.getJSON( URL, function( data) {
 console.log( data );
});
```

Any idea how to fix it or make it working. Is there such a Crossdomain.xml on Icecast that I can give configure or anything else to fix it?

**UPDATE**: 
The above links are two different websites. It is not a sub-domain matter. The links just look alike a bit. Domain A(HTTPS) wants to get JSON from domain B (HTTP).

Comment: This is by design. A secure connection cannot make a request to a non-secure one (at least not without user authorisation). You need to either make your site HTTP too, or the domain you're calling should be changed to HTTPS. Better yet, as both requester and recipient pages are on the same domain, just use a relative path

Comment: @Rory Can't he just make a backend service (in php for example) on his https and from it call other one on http ?

Comment: @LordMidi That's completely false. JSONP is a data format occasionally used for cross domain requests. It has absolutely nothing to do with requests between secure/non secure content.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan They have different domains.

Comment: Or he can just move the `json.xsl` script from subdomain `http://33k.thepuremix.net/json.xsl` to domain `https://www.33k.com`. If it's possible for him ofc.

Comment: @Styx so they do, my mistake. The issue with secure/non-secure content remains then. The security level of the recipient site needs to be the same or higher, not lower as is currently the case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not disputing _that_ :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the comments. The JSON file bongs to an Icecast radio station, that I cannot make it HTTPS. However, would it solve the problem by adding a crossdomain.xml file in my HTTPS server pointing to my server or vice versa? would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling HTTP from HTTPS is blocked by design as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned in the comments (Same Origin Policy), you can either move your script from HTTP to HTTPS or make a backend script (in PHP for example) and call HTTP from it like:

```
JavaScript(HTTPS) -> PHP(HTTPS) -> PHP(HTTP)
JavaScript(HTTPS) <- PHP(HTTPS) <- PHP(HTTP)
```

Reference to creating a http request in PHP: [Http Request in PHP](http://php.net/manual/it/httprequest.send.php)

Here's also some info about [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please check my last comment. in the main post?

Comment: NO. I think there is mistake. these are two different websites. one website is: `thepuremix.net` (HTTP), and one is `33k.com` (HTTPS).

Comment: Correct it was our mistake but still it's not possible, I've edited my answer with info about the `Same Origin Policy` which is the reason it's not possible to do what you want.